# vector of indices

Tags: matlab

I have a 10x10 matrix called A:

I have vector of column numbers:

C = [ 2, 6, 8 ];

I have a vector of row numbers:

R = [1; 3; 7];

The column numbers correspond to each row. i.e. For column 1 we are looking at row numbers given by R, for column 3 we are looking at row numbers given by R and so on.

I want to replace those exact locations in A with some other number 13.

i.e. for each of these locations in matrix A:

```
(1,2) (1,6) (1,8), (3,2), (3, 6), (3,8) I want to insert 13.
```

How do I achieve the above ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do `A(R,C) = 13` .......

Answer (score 0):

As dlavila pointed out, you can do `A(R,C) = 13` wich would be the best and easiest. Nevertheless I have written a longer code involving the `eval` function that you might find useful in the future:

```
for ii=1:length(C)
    for jj =1:length(R)
        eval(strcat('A(', num2str(C(ii)), ',',num2str(R(jj)),')=13;'))
    end
end
```

Both give the same results.

Comment: Why would this ever be more useful than MATLAB's native indexing?

Comment: It wouldn't, but it's something I find often useful, so I decided to share it

Comment: Generally it's best to avoid `eval`: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/